# Why didn't dragon fire burn and kill the Night King?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

It's strange that the Night King wasn't harmed when the dragon spit fire at him in *Game of Thrones* S08E03, because Valyrian steel killed him and what makes Valyrian steel different from regular steel is that it is originally made from dragon's fire. So it would seem that dragon fire would be more effective. Unless I'm wrong about this.

Comment: [Same question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/211202/67911) over on SFF. Also I'm fairly sure it's unconfirmed if Valyrian steel is actually made with dragon fire, it's only a theory since it was made by people with lots of dragons.

Comment: Possibly with dragon fire, but most likely forged with magic.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question, right, so why the downvotes?

Comment: One thing we do have as a sort of clue is that fire has given way before him in the past, like during the assault on the (previous) Three-Eyed Raven's cave. He seemingly has some power over fire or resistance to it. It doesn't seem likely we will learn more about him, but one could speculate he has Targeryan blood in him. We don't know much about the original White Walker created by the Children, but we do know the Night King created all the other White Walkers in the TV series, seemingly from Craster's "sacrifices".

Comment: He's very very cold

Comment: He can absorb all ninjutsu.

Comment: We should definitely learn more about him (and the magic around him) if the prequel series gets picked up since the synopsis mentions "the origins of the White Walkers". I'm curently theorizing that John Hefferman is playing the younger human version of The Night King. (Toby Regbo was my original thought, until John was cast). If they're really done with TNK, Azor Ahai propchecy, and/or the far past on GOT, I think they missed a good opportunity to give people more incentive to watch the prequel by not dropping some kind of bone there, but maybe we're not done?!

Answer (score 6):

## Out of universe reason.

As explained in the inside the episode, if the plan worked, that would have been dull.

> "We thought it was important that whatever the plan was it doesn't
> just work because that would be dull.
>
> "There's no reason to know for certain that the fire wouldn't kill or
> destroy the Night King, but there's also no particular reason to
> believe that it would.
>
> "Then a few moments after this happens, the Night King brings them a
> whole larger undead problem by taking all of their own who have been
> killed in the course of this battle and turning them into the enemy."

So, David Weiss believes that there is "no reason to know for certain that fire could kill the Night King."

Comment: What a terrible way of storytelling, then.

Comment: I completely agree. Maybe if there were clues that the Night King was a targaryen or something...